# Can't access properties of req.user on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have a Node server running with Passport and I'm having trouble accessing the properties of req.user on my server.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
      isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
      user: req.user
  });
console.log(req.user);
});
```

This works fine and displays the console.log as:

```
{ confirmation: 'x', id: 'x', balance: x }
```

in my Git Bash, but if I try to make that same console.log req.user.confirmation, it kills my server and gives me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirmation' of undefined".
If I try to send req.user to my client side JS, say as data.user, I can read data.user.confirmation without a problem. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You should show how you're trying to "send req.user" to your client side JS.

Comment: I'm using Socket.io within that app.get where the console.log is. 'io.emit(('endGame'), {jackpot: jackpotVal, 
                                 user: req.user
                                });' And moving the console.log doesn't change anything, just crashes the server immediately that way.